# If condition and logical comparision not working

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements, logical-operators

```
struct data_struct * search_in_list(char * val, struct data_struct * * prev) {

    char * dat = NULL;
    char * dat2 = NULL;
    struct data_struct * ptr = head;
    struct data_struct * tmp = NULL;
    bool found = false;

    printf("\n Searching the list for value [%s] ...found is.%d\n", val, found);

    while (ptr != NULL) {
        printf("\n ptr !=null .....Searching the list for value ");
        dat = ptr - > val;
        dat2 = val;

        printf("hello world %s.......%s", dat, dat2);

        if (dat == dat2)         // ** here **
            printf("Hello !!!"); // ** here **

        found = (val == ptr - > val);

        printf("the data is%d", found);

        if (found) {

            printf("\n ptr val if......Searching the list for value [%s] ", ptr - > val);
            found = true;
            break;
        } else {

            printf("\n else found....Searching the list for value [%s] ", ptr - > val);
            tmp = ptr;
            ptr = ptr - > next;
        }
    }

    if (true == found) {

        ptr = ptr - > next;
        printf("\n truefound...Searching the list for value [%s] ", ptr - > val);
        if (prev)
            * prev = tmp;

        return ptr;
    } else {
        printf("\n Searching the list for value [%s] ", ptr - > val);

        return NULL;
    }
}
```

The below condition is not working:

```
if (dat == dat2)
    printf("Hello !!!");
```

Any idea why?

If I compare `("serverip" == "serverip")` this works OK.

But if I say `( ptr->val == val)`, this does not work and I don't know why.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `printf("hello world %s.......%s",dat,dat2);` what is that you get here?

Answer (score 0):

because you are comparing a value with an address:

```
char* val; //this is a pointer
struct data_struct *ptr = head; //this is also a pointer
char *dat=NULL; //pointer
char *dat2=NULL; //pointer

dat = ptr->val;  //you assign a pointer the value of one element in a linked list?!
dat2 = val;  //dat2 points to the same address as val
```

I thinks it's clear to see why it does not work.
Solution (other than reading up on pointers):

```
*dat = ptr->val; 
dat2 = val;

if (*dat == *dat2) //compare the 2 values
```

Just to summarize:

```
char *p; //this is a pointer to char
 p //this is the address p points to
*p //this is the value at the address p points to
```

Comment: try printing dat->val and *dat2; maybe the two actually are not the same. I'm not sure why you expect them to be the same, there is nothing in the code to suggest they have to be.

Comment: I just realized I had made a mistake and corrected it. Try this version.

Comment: that's not the issue. The issue is that he tries to compare two strings with == in C which simply won't work. He needs to use strcmp() instead and then it should work.

Comment: @pfannkuchen_gesicht what are you talking about? the comparison is between two bytes or chars; Strcmp() is for strings; the fact that you are dealing with char* does not mean you are dealing with strings.

Comment: from the question it's clear that he wants to compare two strings, look at the end of the question "Any idea why. If I compare ("serverip" == "serverip") this works ok..". Also the fact that he wants to print val with %s in the printf statement is a give-away. Please refrain from downvoting answers if you don't understand the intentions of the OPs question.

Comment: @pfannkuchen_gesicht actually that only shows that he does not understand pointers. There is no indication about what data_struct looks like or what it contains

Comment: so you just assume it's single chars then? Why is that? It could either be a single char or a string and from the whole question post it's quite obvious that he wants to compare strings. Why else would he make his question clear with a string comparison at the end?(" if("serverip" == "serverip") "). Also avoid making assumptions, better ask OP to clarify if he wants to compare chars or strings.

Answer (score 0):

If the `"=="` operator works properly, that could simply mean that your values being compared are not equal -- but not necessarily the correct ones. Are you sure that your `ptr` pointer is initialized to the correct address?
Try to print both values to see yourself if the problem really is in the comparison.
It looks to me that the problem is with the pointer that doesn't point the right address.

Comment: You could've commented this instead. Welcome to Stack overflow...You write an answer only if you feel that it really resolves the Original Post (OP). Giving a generalized statements doesn't help the person. In that case you should be adding a comment to question.

Answer (score 0):

you're just comparing the pointer addresses at this point. What you probably want is to compare the string contents and for that you need to use strcmp(). It will return the difference between the input strings, if they are equal the return value will be 0.

So try this instead:

```
if (strcmp(dat, dat2) == 0)
  printf("Hello !!!");
```

Comment: @Pandrei char* pointers can point to strings. Also from the question it's clear he wants to compare two strings, see the end of the question "Any idea why. If I compare ("serverip" == "serverip") this works ok.."

Comment: @user1421147 no problem! :) If you like the answer, please accept it, so the question is marked as solved.